# jQuery datatable doesn't print all the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, jquery-pagination

I am using jQuery Datatable(jQuery version:jquery-3.1.1.min.js). I need to print all data in the tables(in my scenario I have 56 rows, 10 records per page then it becomes 6 pages).but it only prints some part of data(36 records). but I have pdf function also.it works fine. when hit pdf button it generate pdf with all the recodes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/dataTables/dataTables.buttons.min.js' />"></script>   
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/dataTables/buttons.print.min.js' />"></script>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#adTable').DataTable({
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                         'pdf', 'print'
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>



    <table id="adTable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Status</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="obj" items="${list}" varStatus="loop">
                <tr>
                    <td>${loop.index+1}</td>
                    <td>${obj.subject}</td>
                    <td>${obj.category}</td>
                    <td>${obj.status}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.the issue happens because of my CSS file.
there is a css file that overrides my html body tag  overflow-x

my external css file looks like bellow

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #4f5f6f;
    overflow-x: hidden; }
```

I changed to bellow.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #4f5f6f;
    overflow-x: visible; }
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use below code for `print all`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print all',
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        selected: null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print selected'
            }
        ],
        select: true
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I tried but doesn't work.it gives same output it doesn't print all recodes

Comment: s.jone will you put below links of js

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js

Comment: I used above like bellow  <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js " ></script>
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js " ></script>
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js " ></script>
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js " ></script>
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js" ></script>   but same reasult. no any deference..thanks you very much for effort